# What does "$root: &" mean in sass?

Tags: variables, sass

I'm trying to understand sass files of Splide ( https://splidejs.com/ ).

In many files there are codes like this one

```
.splide {
    $root: &;

    &--ttb {
        > #{$root}__pagination {
            display:        flex;
            right:          1em;
            bottom:         50%;
            left:           auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            transform:      translate(0, 50%);

            #{$root}__pagination__page {
                width:  $indicator-height;
                height: $indicator-width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What the `$root: &;` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your snippet, `$root` is just the name of the variable.
You could give it another name, like `$foo`.

`$root: &` is equivalent here to `$root: .splide` as `&` in sass refers to the parent selector.

**It means that:**

```
.splide {
    $root: &;

    &--ttb {
        > #{$root}__pagination {
            display:        flex;
            right:          1em;
            bottom:         50%;
            left:           auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            transform:      translate(0, 50%);

            #{$root}__pagination__page {
                width:  $indicator-height;
                height: $indicator-width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Is equivalent to:**

```
.splide {
    &--ttb {
        > .splide__pagination {
            display:        flex;
            right:          1em;
            bottom:         50%;
            left:           auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            transform:      translate(0, 50%);

            .splide__pagination__page {
                width:  $indicator-height;
                height: $indicator-width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And will compile to:**

```
.splide--ttb > .splide__pagination {}
.splide--ttb > .splide__pagination .splide__pagination__page {}
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question: so is `$root: &;` useless?

Comment: I wouldn't say useless. In this case, if you had to change to name of the class you would just change the first line, this way it's less prone to error.

Comment: If I did answer your question, you can accept this answer. If you need any more details about your question, don't hesitate. ;)